# Conversion of string representation of number in base2 to 64 bit signed integer in C

Tags: c#, c, hex

In C# code, I am having line as follows

```
string DE1Hex = String.Format("{0:X1}", Convert.ToInt64(newDE1, 2));
```

I am trying to implement in C(not C++) in my project.

Tried 
-->for 2nd argument

```
char *pEnd;
long long ll_i1;
ll_i1 = strtoll (newDE1, &pEnd, 2);
```

-->1st argument I am not sure what is this "{0:X1}"

C# is new to me.I am fair in C
Please Guide me in this conversion.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to tell us with this: "*Tried -->for 2nd argument*"

Comment: Please, what *does* work, what doesn't?

Comment: There is a nice example on how to use `strtoll()` at the bottom of this man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: Parameters of String.Format(1st,2nd); .Hex tag is not needed.I want to know strtoll is equivalent of Convert.ToInt64 because from standard I see both returns long long

Comment: @user2357643, yes, strtoll() is the right function.